# Using a program that likely has a trojan horse?

Tags: malware, windows, virus, antivirus

- OP wants to back up his Blu-ray/4K collection to a HDD.
- OP suspects that a very popular program that makes MKVs is actually a trojan horse that infects host computer's USB drives, which can later be used for anything else.
- OP is considering purchasing a cheap, used laptop to run this program on and rip his collection, prior to transferring files to mass network storage.
- How would OP ensure that the shady software doesn't infect his other computers/home network, in the case that this program infects the host's USB drives?

Or should one give up altogether in this instance and resort to something else?

Comment: This is a bit of a contrived scenario that doesn't make sense. If you suspect the USB is infected, you just reformat the USB. If you are worried about BadUSB, then you simply use a USB that isn't vulnerable to that. But why would a MKV program infect USB? The far greater risk, and likelihood, is that the malicious program would embed malware into the files it creates. This is too much of a "strawman" or thought experiment with too many potential variables to answer on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has [Windows Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview), which can quickly spin up a contained environment that you can install the software on and rip the discs.

This is pre-packaged as part of Windows 10 Professional, and can be [installed on Windows 10 Home](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_enable_windows_sandbox_in_windows_10_home.html) which I have successfully done.

Or look for a non-spyware open-sourced alternative.

Comment: Or use a VM, or not save to USB at all, or ... there are far too many ways to address this scenario.